# Sequential Const Field Values

Tags: c#

I have classes like this

```
class MyClass{
    const int Item1 = 1;
    const int Item2 = 2;
    const int Item3 = 3;
    ...
}
class MySecondClass : MyClass
{
    const int Item1 = 4;
    const int Item2 = 5;
    const int Item3 = 6;
    ...
}
```

Is there an automatic way to set these values making sure they are sequential and still const? We have had problems on merges where two developers add an item and we end up with two items with the same value.

Currently we check if this happens with unit tests and fix it if a test breaks. But it would be better we could do something like this during compilation:

```
int i=0;
class MyClass{
    const int Item1 = i;
    const int Item2 = ++i;
    const int Item3 = ++i;
    ...
}
class MySecondClass : MyClass{
    const int Item4 = ++i;
    const int Item5 = ++i;
    const int Item6 = ++i;
    ...
}
```

Edit:
This is legacy code in dozens of classes I can't change the structure to an enum.

Comment: I see your question has changed significantly since I gave my answer. Why must the constants be declared across two classes? I do not know of a way to achieve this. You can use `public static readonly int x = i++;` and `public static int i = 0;` but [the initialization order is undefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Edited again, hope it's clearer. MySecondClass has to have the items used in the base class and add its own items. Alot of classes inherit from MyClass and they all have to have this behavior.

Comment: There is no way with `const` fields; the values have to be compile time constants.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A
{
  static A() { }

  protected static int i = 0;

  public static readonly int Item1 = i++;
  public static readonly int Item2 = i++;
  public static readonly int Item3 = i++;

}

class B : A
{
  static B() { }

  public static readonly int Item4 = i++;
  public static readonly int Item5 = i++;
  public static readonly int Item6 = i++;
}
```

You cannot use `const` because `i++` is not considered a constant expression, but `static readonly` is a similar constraint.

According to [10.4.5.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx) it is necessary to explicitly include the static constructors to inherit the initialisation order rules for static constructors.

According to [10.11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612(v=vs.71).aspx):

> If a class contains any static fields with initializers, those
>   initializers are executed in textual order immediately prior to
>   executing the static constructor.

And:

> The static constructor for a class executes at most once in a given
>   application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered
>   by the first of the following events to occur within an application
>   domain:
>
> - An instance of the class is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class are referenced.

Because `B` references the static member `i` of `A`, the static constructor of `A` must execute first. Therefore you should be guaranteed (if I have interpreted this all correctly) that `Item1 == 0, …, Item6 == 5` *provided that* there are no other descendants of `A` which also mutate `i`.

If you add another descendant `C` to `A` then you need to reference a static field of `B` from `C` if you wish to order `B` before `C` (or vice versa).

---

#### Old Answer (before the question was changed)

How about an enum?

```
enum Items : int
{
  Item1 = 1,
  Item2,
  Item3,
  // …
}
```

You can get your ints back out:

```
var x = (int)Items.Item1;
```

- [Enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Comment: How do you make sure the enums are sequential?

Comment: From the "Enums" link I provided: "By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1. For example, in the following enumeration, Sat is 0, Sun is 1, Mon is 2, and so forth". There is more information there if you'd like it.

Comment: Sorry, enums won't work because these values have to be inherited. I edited the question with this information.

Comment: Also this is legacy code in dozens of classes I can't change the structure to an enum.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single class with all the constants, and the class contains nothing else, an enum is appropriate (see erisco's answer).

For more complex cases like the one you describe in your edited question, your best bet is probably code generation. You can make the classes [partial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), and generate part of the class from a [T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), which allows you to implement any logic you like for the generated code.